# so i was just trying to implement a simple linked list in C++ but i dont seem to get past a segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I have fixed some of the problems but still can't get past the segmentation fault in while loop of append function where the next of temp is updated.i have seen the segmentation fault in debugger when i stepped into the particular line. also a side note while posting here it gives many errors any way i can fix those

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    int data;
    node* next;
    node()
    {
        data=0;
        next=nullptr;
    }
    node(int value)
    {
        data=value;

    }

    void setnext(node* obj)
    {
        next=obj;
    }
};
class linkedlist{
public:
    node* head;
    node* tail;
    linkedlist()
    {
        head=nullptr;
        tail=nullptr;
    }
    void prepend(int data)
    {
        node* temp=new node(data);
        temp->setnext(head); //updates the new next pointer
        head=temp; //updates the head with new address
    }

    void append(int data)
    {
        node* temp=new node(data);
        if(head==nullptr)
        {
            cout<<"the linked list is empty";
            head=temp;
            tail=temp;
            temp=nullptr;
        }
        else {

            while (temp!= nullptr)
            {
                temp = temp->next; //segmentation fault here
            }
            tail->setnext(temp);
            tail = temp; //updates the tail with new address
            }
        }
    void display()
    {
        node* temp=head;

        while(temp!=nullptr)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<"->";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        cout<<"NULL";
    }
};
int main()
{
    linkedlist obj;
    obj.prepend(1);
    obj.append(2);
    obj.append(3);
    obj.display();
}
```

Comment: `void* setnext(node* obj)` does not return anything, thats undefined behavior. You should turn on compiler warnings and fix them

Comment: You should not comment this out: `//next=nullptr;`

Comment: the `node(int value)` constructor does not initialize `next`, so reading it later is undefined behavior as well

Comment: acutally your code has lots of uninitialized pointers. Always initialize members in the constructor. When a pointer is not initialized, the check for `NULL` does not help (btw rather use `nullptr`)

Comment: Recommendation, step through the code with whatever debugging utility came with your development tools and pay special attention to the values in the variables in use. If you see an unexpected value, find out how it got there because in programming the unexpected is almost always a bug. And the rest of the time the unexpected is because of bad expectations. Either way, you need to fix the problem before continuing.

Comment: This code has a whole lot of problems. Uninitialized members, absence of necessary functionality (e.g. you never actually set a head if there is none), or weird initialized members like `data='\0'` with `data` being of type `int` (so why not use `data=0`?).

Answer (score 2):

After creating a new `linkedlist`, the default constructor of `linkedlist` should have initialized `node* head` and `node* tail` to `nullptr`.

Thus, the call `obj.prepend(1);` after `linkedlist obj;` does not prepend `1` into `obj`. As a result, `node* head` and `node* tail` are still both `nullptr`.

After that, if you call `obj.append(2);`, then `tail->setnext(temp);` results in a Segmentation Fault as `tail` is `nullptr`.

You should have checked whether the linkedlist is empty in `linkedlist::prepend` and `linkedlist::append`, if so, `node* head` and `node* tail` need to be properly initialized.

Comment: I have uploaded an edited code in which I have fixed some of the errors. prepend seems to be working fine now. could you point out what could be causing the segmentation fault(line mentioned in the code)?

Comment: 1. in void prepend(int data), you forgot to set node* tail if it is nullptr. 2. in void append(int data), what is the purpose of the while (temp!= nullptr) loop?

Comment: 1.i didn't set it in that case as i just set the head to a new node. 2.the purpose of this while loop is to traverse through the nodes until it reaches the tail. i made another change:
while(temp->next!=nullptr)

Answer (score 0):

In your append() function you're using the 'tail' member before you've assigned a value to it.